# php regex - Delete phrase

Tags: php, regex

I have a long string that has imbedded in it: `"ABC_1_"` and `"ABC_2_"` and `"ABC_3_"` etc.

For example:

```
"lorum ipsum ABC_1_ doit more ABC_3_ and so on".
```

I need to write a PHP  preg_replace that will remove the 6 characters (`ABC_xx`) if the first 4 are `"ABC_"` and  return the full remaining string, in my example:

```
"lorum ipsum  doit more  and so on".
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use preg_replace with regular expression: `(ABC_.{2} )`

```
$string = "lorum ipsum ABC_1_ doit more ABC_3_ and so on";
$pattern = "/(ABC_.{2})/";
$replacement = "";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Thanks!  Nice bass clef icon!

Comment: Id didn't know what's it called. Now I know :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$s = preg_replace('/\bABC_../', '', $s);
```

The `\b` matches a word boundary, and the dots match any character (apart from new line).

Full example:

```
<?php
$s = 'ABC_1_foo lorum ipsum ABC_1_ doit more ABC_3_ and so on'; 
$s = preg_replace('/\bABC_../', '', $s);
echo $s;
?>
```

Result:

```
foo lorum ipsum  doit more  and so on
```

[(ideone)](http://ideone.com/5ubkc)

Comment: this works. I removed the \b because the phrase may not be on a word boundary. But I didn't specify that in my question. THANKS!!!

Comment: @sdfor: The reason for the word boundary was so that it doesn't accidentally match DABC_D_. But if you want that to match then yes you don't need the word boundary.